# Uber H3 geoToH3 is not working in React Native

Tags: react-native, geospatial, react-native-ios, h3

I am developing simple grid location based application in **React Native** using **Uber H3**. I installed H3 by
`npm install h3-js`. Then
I created a file to read H3Index from latitude and longitude.

```
    import {geoToH3} from 'h3-js';
    const getH3Index = () => {
        const result = geoToH3(37.3615593, -122.0553238, 7);
        console.log(result);
    };
```

When I start to run my React Native application, app hangs on white screen(splash screen) and blocks the whole application. If I comment these lines, app works fine. If uncomment this line, both iOS and Android app is not working.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see https://github.com/uber/h3-js/issues/35

This is likely due to a `document is not defined` error. See the issue thread for several possible workarounds, including [this fork](https://github.com/realPrimoh/h3-reactnative) which is intended for React Native.